# How to assign new value to computed in VueJS

Tags: vue.js

I am getting a data from backend by mapGetter. I want to use this data as v-model inside my v-datepicker component. And that's why I am using computed property with getter and setter to access this data.

```
dDate: {
  get () {
    return this.formatDate(this.CURRENT_REQUEST.docDate.toString().substring(0, 10))
  },
  set () {}
}
```

`CURRENT_REQUEST` returns me an object and I select from this object property `docDate`.

Also I have an input `dateDoc`. I'm watching for changes in this input. And I want to assign changed value of `dateDoc` to `this.dDate`. So I am using watch as below.

```
watch: {
  dateDoc (val) {
    this.dDate = this.formatDate(this.dateDoc)
  }
},
```

When I assign new value for `this.dDate` its value is not changing. Where is the mistake? Why I can not change value of `this.dDate`? Is that a reactivity problem? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Well, your computed _setter_ is empty so trying to set a value will never do anything. It's not clear what the actual data properties are that should drive your computed (is it `dateDoc` or `CURRENT_REQUEST.docDate`?). Could you please explain what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62870692/edit) to show the data properties you're using and explain in plain words how they should drive your computed values. Where are you using the computed property? Why does it need a separate _getter_ and _setter_?

Comment: Edited my question. I hope it is clear enough now...

Comment: If your data is coming from Vuex, you will need to commit a mutation to change it. You can see an example here ~ https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#two-way-computed-property

Comment: Thank you very much! It is almost solved my problem! Now I can change value by mutation. But somehow I get ```undefined.undefined.07.07.2020``` instead of ```07.07.2020```. I guess I have to check my code. Thank you very much for help! I could mark it as SOLVE if it was seperate answer.